# ThunderBird 115 - How to Hide the Unified Toolbar with CSS?

Tags: thunderbird, css

[The Unified Toolbar](https://assets-prod.sumo.prod.webservices.mozgcp.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2023-05-24-15-35-00-da152a.png) is of no use to me and I would life to turn it off.

I have tried messing the with Dev Tools and the `userChrome` file, just to confirm my `userChrome` file works, the following highlights folders on the left panel:

```
/* Thunderbird userChrome.css */

#folderTree li[data-server-type] > div.container {
    color: rgb(40, 134, 56) !important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 200) !important;
 }
 #folderTree li[data-server-type] > div.container > span.name {
    font-weight: 1200 !important;
 }
```

Using the DevTools I was able to temporarily hide the Unified toolbar, I copied the style, pasted it into the `userChrome` file, the `userChrome` files total content is:

```
/* Thunderbird userChrome.css */
 #unifiedToolbar {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding-block: var(--unified-toolbar-padding);
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

But when I reopen Thunderbird, the toolbar is still visible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to paste just the following into the userChrome.css file: `#unifiedToolbar {  visibility: collapse; }`. More info in [link](https://support.mozilla.org/hu/questions/1418113).